# Proving a commitment hides the value hidden in an encrypted puzzle

Tags: timed-release

I am making a protocol that has one missing piece.  It involves 2 non-trusted party $A$ and $B$ and a semihonest third party $C$.  This protocol has a contingency step where if $A$ leaves prematurely, $B$ is supposed receive time locked puzzle.  It is important that $B$ cannot get the puzzle early.  The puzzle ensures that after a period of time, $B$ will get a value he is supposed to get, but not immediately.  Neither $A$ nor $B$ want $C$ to be able to learn the value hidden in the puzzle (therefore $C$ can't have the puzzle), and $B$ shouldn't be able to start working on the puzzle until $A$ leaves and $C$ reveals the puzzle.  $A$ also needs to prove to $B$ that the value hidden in the puzzle matches a commitment (preferably Pedersen) at the beginning of the protocol.  Note that once $A$ leaves, $C$ wishes to leave almost immediately (for important structural reasons), so it can't just be an encryption to which $C$ holds the key and $C$ gives it to $B$.

My question is does such a system currently exist?  This system being as follows: $A$ creates a time locked puzzle that cannot be worked on by $B$ until a value is released while still proving that the puzzle hides the same value as a commitment.

I know that such a scheme can be created by going down to the bit-level, but I would strongly prefer a more efficient solution.

I am aiming for a sequential puzzle that takes around 2 hours for a powerful computer to solve, akin to [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/635.pdf).

TLDR:  Is there a way to encrypt a puzzle such that the puzzle cannot be worked on until it is decrypted while still proving that the solution to the puzzle matches a commitment?

Comment: This is a XY problem, you propose the solution already along your problem. You don't need a timelocked something. You could also have a secret shared between B and C, where C sends his share to B if A leaves. Nothing fancy, just let A create the shares and a ZK proof that the shares actually contain what they are supposed to contain.

Comment: That solution won't work.  $C$ can't wait around after $A$ leaves, but $B$ can't have the secret until some time has passed.  If $B$ has the value immediately, it poses a problem for $A$, and $A$ leaving isn't necessarily malicious.